# Where is M-x compile?

Tags: c, compile

I have a basic C file open in c-mode:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  return 0;
};
```

I'm trying to compile it.  I type `M-x compile` [expecting to be asked to set my compile command and then run it](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CompileCommand), but I don't have an `M-x compile` at all.  Instead the minibuffer tries to autocomplete with:

```
Click on a completion to select it.
In this buffer, type RET to select the completion near point.

Possible completions are:
compile-defun
compile-goto-error
compile-mouse-goto-error
```

What mode do I need to be in for `M-x compile` to exist?

### Update

I am running `GNU Emacs 27.0.50 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.30)`

And in my `init.el` contains:

```lisp
(require 'compile)
```

Comment: That should be autoloaded.  What does `M-x emacs-version` report? (You can copy it from the messages buffer; `C-h e` for that.)

Comment: It's in `compile.el` btw, so you could always `M-x load-library` manually, or `(require 'compile)` in your init file.

Comment: OK, cool.  I expected it to be autoloaded and was surprised it is not!  I have updated my question with this information.

Comment: `M-x load-library` did it, but having it in my init.el did not.

Comment: Try updating to 27.0.92 -- maybe there was a bug in whatever revision of 27.0.50 you compiled from.

Comment: Do you have the `'c-mode-hook` too, after the `require 'compile` line in `init.el` ?

Comment: Romario, I do not have the linked code hook because I prefer the default behavior of asking me.